# Error while localy connecting to MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1130

Today when I wanted to connect to my local MySQL server, I got an error message from server:

> Host '192.168.1.100' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.

What does this mean? My machine is a MacBook Pro with OSX Lion. Yesterday everything was fine, but today when I want connect mysql with Eclipse, I got this error. In Navicat everything work fine, I can open shemas and write select.

Comment: Use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead of the LAN IP.

Comment: So local = on your local machine? Can you show the code you are using to connect?

Comment: i use this string to connect to database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate-test and I don't use LAN IP. i use localhost

Comment: but when I'm using 127.0.0.1 in the string of connection, everything is OK. why system see localhost as my lan ip?